# is exponential diophantine over Qp

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, fields, diophantine-equations

Thanks to Matiyasevic, we all know that exponential is diophantine over the integers. Also, thanks to transcendental number theory, we know that exponential is not diophantine over the rationals. So the question now, is exponential, if definable, diophantine over the $p$-adics?